# How to randomly select 2 cells from a horizontal range in Google Sheet or R

Tags: r, google-sheets

I need to pick randomly 2 cells from a row (specific range/columns of the row).

```
Al  Em  Kev
1   1   2
3   2   3
2   2   1
3   3   3
```

output:

```
rand 1  rand 2
2         1
3         2
2         2
3         3
```

The results need to be unique: the same cell cannot be returned both times.

It would be quicker to do it in Google sheets right now, but an answer using R would be fine as well.

Thanks guys

Comment: Try with `t(apply(data, 1, function(x) sample(x, 2)))`

Comment: can you be more specific as to how do I select the range from which to sample?

Comment: Not clear about your comment.  Perhaps `t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) sample(Reduce(':', range(x)), 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `apply`

```
t(apply(data, 1, function(x) sample(x, 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks.
I what if I have a certain string in the data, and if "sample" returns that string I would like it to sample again/avoid sampling that mentioned string.

Comment: @KantushovHerman. IN that case, use `unique` i.e. `sample(unique(x), 2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SPLIT(INDIRECT(CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,67))&ROW())&
   "♥"&INDIRECT(CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,67))&ROW()),"♥")
```

[image: 0]